# How to accelerate mcsqs to get quasi-random structure?

Tags: special-quasirandom-structures, alloy-theoretic-automated-toolkit, disorder

I'd like to generate a supercell of Cd0.5Zn0.5S which includes 108 atoms, and I tried to use `mpirun -np 64 mcsqs -n 108` to get the supercell, but according to the log of `mcsqs`, the program runs very slowly, how could I make the program run faster?

Here is the log of mcsqs:

```
OObjective_function= -0.944454
Correlations_mismatch=  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.111111    -0.111111   -0.111111   -0.111111   -0.111Objective_function= -0.944454
Correlations_mismatch=  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.111111   -0.111111   0.111111    -0.111111   -0.111111
0.111111    0.111111
454
Correlations_mismatch=  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.111111    0.111111    -0.111111   -0.111111   -0.111111
11  0.111111
Objective_function= -0.944454
Correlations_mismatch=  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.111111    -0.111111   -0.111111   -0.111111   -0.111111
```

Here is the result I got after running `mcsqs` for a few days which doesn't seems quite good:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mcsqs is not supported by mpi. Each process of mcsqs can be run on only one core. However, as a Monte Carlo method, you can still parallelize. You can concurrently run multiple processes on different cores, but with each process having a different random seed.

For example,

```
mcsqs -n=108 -ip=1 -sd=933009 &
mcsqs -n=108 -ip=2 -sd=112980 &
.
.
.

mcsqs -n=108 -ip=64 -sd=933009 &
```

Extra resource: [How to use SQS for disordered materials](https://cniu.me/2017/08/05/SQS.html)

Comment: do I need to create a folder for each macaws process or I could run these process in the same folder?